# Change Tabs and Panels

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, shinydashboard, menuitem

I want to make something like the `tabsetPanel` menu inside the `sidebarMenu`, being able to use either to get to the different panels. I also want the different `sidebarMenus` to take you to the page the panels are on.

I have a shiny dashboard with multiple tabs.

```
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "Tabs",
    menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "Tab1"),
    menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2"),
    menuItem("Tab3", tabName = "Tab3")
) )
```

I have a body on Tab1 with `tabsetPanels`.

```
dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Tab1",
      tabsetPanel(id = "Panels",
        tabPanel(tabName = "Panel1"),
        tabPanel(tabName = "Panel2")
) ) ) )
```

When I click on "Tab1" I want to be brought to tabItem "Tab1" and tabPanel "Panel1". When I click on "Tab2" I want to be brought to tabItem "Tab1" and tabPanel "Panel2". When I click on "Tab3" I want to be brought to tabItem "Tab1" and tabPanel "Panel3".

I have a `server` code like this:

```
observeEvent(input$Tabs, {
  selectedTab <- input$Tabs
  if (selectedTab == "Tab1" || selectedTab == "Tab2" || selectedTab == "Tab3") {
    updateTabItems(inputId = "Tabs", selected = "Tab1") 
# The panels change correctly with this above line commented out.
# The menuItems change correctly without this above line commented out.
    if (selectedTab == "Tab1") {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "Panels", selected = "Panel1")
    } else if (selectedTab == "Tab2") {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "Panels", selected = "Panel2")
    } else if (selectedTab == "Tab3") {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "Panels", selected = "Panel3")
    }
  }
})
```

Issues:

1. Without the one line commented, it takes me to "Tab1" for all three menuItems but all three take me to "Panel1" instead of the specified panel.
2. With the one line commented, you can't reselect "Tab2" if you are already on it. If I hit "Tab2" Then hit "Panel3", I can't hit "Tab2" again to go to "Panel2" without clicking on another menuItem first.

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).